# Simple floor problem Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is it true that for any positive $x, y$ that if $x \leq y$ then $\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{y}{2} \rfloor$?

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far just some examples and it seems to hold. But it just seems so simple that I don't know where to begin

Comment: $a-1\lt\lfloor a\rfloor\le a$

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use this.

Comment: Umm... the floor function is monotonic.

Answer (score 3):

Given that, $ x \leq y $, where x, y $\in R^+$,
which implies $ x/2 \leq y/2 $

Splitting x and y to integer and fractional part, $ \left \lfloor x/2 \right \rfloor $ +  { $x/2$ } $ \leq \left \lfloor y/2 \right \rfloor $ +  {$ y/2 $}

Rearranging terms, $ \left \lfloor x/2 \right \rfloor $ - $ \left \lfloor y/2 \right \rfloor  \leq $ {$ y/2 $} - { $ x/2 $}

Now since $0 \leq x/2, y/2 < 1$,  we have  -1 < { $ y/2 $ } - {$ x/2 $} < 1 ,

Replacing R.H.S., using the above observation, we get
 $ \left \lfloor x/2 \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor y/2 \right \rfloor < 1$

Since LHS is an integer function and it should be less than 1, the value it can achieve is maximum 0, so we can write the above equation as  $ \left \lfloor x/2 \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor y/2 \right \rfloor \leq 0$

which gives, 
$ \left \lfloor x/2 \right \rfloor  \leq \left \lfloor y/2 \right \rfloor $

Hence proved

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\lfloor{x/2\rfloor}+\lfloor{y/2\rfloor}=x/2-\{x/2\}+y/2-\{y/2\}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The floor function is defined as
$$\lfloor x\rfloor = \mathrm{max}\{k\in\mathbb Z : k\leq x\}$$
for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: so $\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor = \max\{k \in \mathbb{Z} : k \leq x / 2\} := k_1$ and $\lfloor \frac{y}{2} \rfloor = \max\{k \in \mathbb{Z} : k \leq y / 2\} := k_2$ but how do I know that $k_1 \leq k_2$?

Comment: @SeptemberSummers Since $x\leq y$, $\frac{x}{2} \leq \frac{y}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Contrapositive:

If $\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor\gt \lfloor \frac y2\rfloor,$ then, since these are integers, $\lfloor\frac x2\rfloor \ge \lfloor \frac y2\rfloor+1.$

But $\frac x2\ge\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor$ and $\lfloor \frac y2\rfloor\gt\frac y2-1.$

That means $\frac x2>\frac y2$; i.e., $x>y$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it sufficies to show $x \leq y$ implies $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq \lfloor y \rfloor$ (why?). So let $m=\lfloor x \rfloor$, $n=\lfloor y \rfloor$. Since $m,n$ are integers, we have three options, either $m \geq n+1$, $m=n$ or $m \leq n-1$.

First notice we cannot have $m \geq n+1$, for then $x \geq \lfloor x \rfloor=m \geq n+1=\lfloor y \rfloor + 1 > y$, impossible.

Next, note $m=n$ implies $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$, we are done.

Lastly if $m\leq n-1$, then $\lfloor x \rfloor=m\leq n-1 = \lfloor y \rfloor - 1 \leq  \lfloor y \rfloor$.